# How to determine a registry key value on a windows machine? (through cmd)

Tags: cmd

*Hey! Could somebody help me to give a proper way to registry key value through cmd.*

Comment: In future, please do some research and post the problem you have when you can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `REG` command to get info from the Registry through a batch file or at the command prompt.

Use `REG QUERY /?` for more information about the options available.